# Getting value of checked radio button using Material UI Radio

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, material-ui, radio-group

I'm creating a form and now attempting to do some input validation, and I'm struggling to grab the checked value from my radio component.

In one file I have:

```js
<FormControl component="fieldset" name="method-of-payment">
    <RadioGroup onChange={this.handleChange} >
        <FormControlLabel value="credit" control={<Radio />} label="Credit Card"/>
        <FormControlLabel value="check" control={<Radio />} label="Check"/>
        <FormControlLabel value="purchase-order" control={<Radio />} label="Purchase Order"/>
     </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```

And I'm trying to grab the value doing this in another file (it's worked for everything else):

```js
this.setState({
    method-of-payment: document.getElementsByName('method-of-payment')[0].value
})
```

But I'm having no luck getting the correct value.

I appreciate any help.

Edit: here's a link to the documentation I followed: https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like it's likely to be a bug-prone approach, and in general accessing elements directly is a React anti-pattern.

A better way would be to store the checked `<Radio>` element value as a property in your state. Use the `onChange` prop of your `<RadioGroup>` to hook in to when the selection changes, store it in your state and use this in the `value` prop of your containing `<RadioGroup>`.

You should add an event listener and then update your state based on the `value` you can get from the event. If you hook it up like that then you don't have to access the element to find its value - you already know it as it's in your state.

Basic example would go something like this:

```
class MyForm extends Component {
  state = { selected: "credit" };
  handleChange = ev => {
    this.setState({ selected: ev.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    return (
      <FormControl component="fieldset" name="method-of-payment">
        <RadioGroup onChange={this.handleChange} value={selected}>
          <FormControlLabel
            value="credit"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Credit Card"
          />
          <FormControlLabel value="check" control={<Radio />} label="Check" />
          <FormControlLabel
            value="purchase-order"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Purchase Order"
          />
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }
}
```

[Codepen here](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-wave-vmhqz)

Comment: Really appreciate the response! This looks almost identical to my code actually, I probably should've shown everything. The issue is finding a way to grab that current state value from another file, which performs the validation.

Answer (score 0):

it's simpler it looks

```
document.querySelector('[name="method-of-payment"]:checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your on change like below

```
onChange={(e, val)=>console.log(val)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).